# Your Communities - Reputation is out of position

Tags: bug, design

I'm not sure if there has recently been a new update, I did notice the top bar on Super User had changed. However, on each community I visit the reputation alongside that community is out of position.

[image: Example of rep next to communities]

I'm using Firefox so I initially cleared my cache, but still had the same result. I then tested it on Chrome and it worked as normal.

Comment: Ah, your reputation didn't drop. The _position_ of the reputation figures is incorrect. Next time please don't forget the hand drawn red circles. You really confused me here ;)

Comment: @honk Apologies. Requested changes made. I hope these freehand red circles help to make things clearer.

Comment: _"I hope these freehand red circles help to make things clearer."_ - I can only see one circle. And the arrow seems to be redundant. And what do the wiggly lines indicate? That all looks like a jellyfish swimming to the right. Now I'm even more confused :p